# How to prove $f(x)$ is continuous is on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, functional-equations

> Let $f,g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be functions satisfying
>
> 1. $\,f(x-y)=f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)$
> 2. $g(x-y)=g(x)g(y)+f(x)f(y)$
>
> for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and also
>
> 3. $\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(t)}{t}=1$.

Show that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

These conditions are clearly satisfied by
$$\big(g(x),f(x)\big)=(\cos x,\sin x),$$
but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This looks like $f = \sin, g = \cos$. I don't know whether that's the only solution, though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, even though I am not good at english writing. I will think about it

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: the question is good (interesting so that I could not resist adding an answer), but is closed because of lack of effort from OP.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh One can not expect students dealing with problems, such as this, which are unusual and very difficult, to show their effort. There is not much to try, if you haven't solved similar problems. Only students with experience with Mathematical Olympiads, and hard functional equations, can even attempt to solve this problem!

Comment: You can always start by writing out relevant definitions etc.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: agree this is not a run of the mill homework problem. I wonder if I would have solved it when I was a beginner in calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted my comment into a full blown answer.

---

Putting $x=y$ in first equation we get $f(0)=0$. Putting $x=y=0$ in second equation we get $g(0)=g(0)g(0)$ so that either $g(0)=0$ or $g(0)=1$. If $g(0)=0$ then putting $y=0$ in the first equation in question gives us $f(x) =0$ for all $x$ and this is forbidden in question. Hence $g(0)=1$.

Next interchanging the roles of $x, y$ you can easily show that $f$ is odd, $g$ is even. Based on this we get the usual addition formulas $$f(x+y) =f(x) g(y) +f(y) g(x), g(x+y) =g(x) g(y) - f(x) f(y) \tag{1}$$ The limit equation in question shows that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ so that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Next putting $x=y$ in second equation in question we get $$f^2(x)+g^2(x)=1\tag{2}$$ and combined with $(1)$ this gives the relation $$g(2x)=1-2f^{2}(x)\tag{3}$$ Letting $x\to 0$ we get $\lim_{x\to 0}g(2x)=1$ or $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=1$ so that $g$ is also continuous at $0$. Now from equation $(1)$ we can see by letting $y\to 0$ that both $f, g$ are continuous everywhere.

---

You can go a bit further. The limit in question combined with the equations $(1),(3)$ above shows that $f'(x) =g(x), g'(x) =-f(x) $ so that both $f, g$ satisfy the differential equation $y''+y=0$ and by initial values we get that $f(x) =\sin x, g(x) =\cos x$. Thus the conditions given in the question characterize the circular functions.

Comment: wow thank you very much. By the way can I ask why The limit equation in question shows that lim x→0 f(x)=0  ? I can't understand

Comment: @장원봉: that should have been obvious. $f(x) =x(f(x) /x) \to 0\cdot 1=0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: wow thank you very much! I understand